# Finding matching rows

Tags: multidimensional-array, nested-lists, membership, apl, dyalog

Given two matrices *A* and *B* with the same number of columns I would like to know if there are any rows which are the same in *A* and *B*. In Dyalog APL I can use the function *split* like this:

```
(↓A) ∊ ↓B
```

Is there a way to calculate the same result without the split function?

Comment: Btw, with 18.0, you can write `A ∊⍥↓ B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've found is a design flaw in [Membership](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Membership) `∊` in that it implies that the right argument is a set of scalars rather than looking at it as a collection of major cells. This precluded extension according to [Leading axis theory](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Leading_axis_theory). However, [Index of](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Index_Of) `⍳` *was* extended thus, and so we can use the fact that it returns the index beyond the end of of the lookup array when a major cell isn't found:

```
      ⎕← A ← 4 2⍴2 7 1 8 2 8 1 8
2 7
1 8
2 8
1 8
      ⎕← B ← 5 2⍴1 6 1 8 0 3 3 9 8 9
1 6
1 8
0 3
3 9
8 9
      (↓A) ∊ ↓B
0 1 0 1
      Membership ← {(≢⍵) ≥ ⍵⍳⍺}
      A Membership B
0 1 0 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///31HhUdsEBRMFo0e9W4wUzBUMFSwUjIAYSHM5geVMwXKGCmZgOQMFYyC0BLIsuR71TQUpcFRwgjE1HrVNdtRUeNTRBdQ62YnLNzU3KbWoOCOzAGxUtcajzkWPercCVXQuVQAyHvVuftS7qxZhEpIGp///AQ)

This can also be written tacitly as `Membership ← ⊢∘≢ ≥ ⍳⍨`.

Either way, note that avoiding the detour of nested arrays leads to significant speed gains:

```
      A←?1000 4⍴10
      B←?1000 4⍴10
      ]runtime -compare "(↓A) ∊ ↓B" "A Membership B"
                                                                          
  (↓A) ∊ ↓B      → 1.6E¯4 |   0% ⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕⎕ 
  A Membership B → 8.9E¯6 | -95% ⎕⎕
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried to define your membership function in GNU APL but I got a range error in ⍵ ⍳ ⍺. My conclusion is that in GNU APL the left argument of iota must be a vector.

Comment: Right, GNU APL uses [a different extension to dyadic `⍳`](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl.html#Generalized-dyadic-_005b_003f_005d). I used a Dyalog specific feature since you tagged your question [tag:dyalog]. In GNU APL, you can use `Membership←{∨/⍺≡⍤(¯1+≢⍴⍵)⍤(¯1 0+≢⍴⍵)⊢⍵}` in general, or `Membership←{∨/⍺≡⍤1⍤1 2⊢⍵}` in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks! I added the Dyalog tag since the question mentions Dyalog APL.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Oh wow, I completely misunderstood your question. You mean to ask how to write Dyalog's monadic `↓` in GNU APL. Well, that's `⊂⍤1` although what you often need is to split into major cells, i.e. `⊂⍤¯1`.

Comment: No, your interpretation of the question was mostly correct; what I'm looking for is a portable way to implement *RowMemberOf* so to speak. Now I also know how to implement the function *split*.

Answer (score 0):

Something like A⍳B would show not only membership but location of equal rows.